# How do I make the stars blink?

Tags: modifiers, node-editor, animation-nodes, shader-nodes

I am having some trouble making my stars blink. I am new to blender... But not new to art and 3D.

I made this night sky scene in Blender 3.2.0. I have uploaded some pics on the scene and the node settings.

[image: Starry Night]

[image: Starry Night Nodes]

Comment: Keyframe along the timeline, the varying emission strength after adding an emission shader to the star mesh.

Answer (score 3):

You can get something really simple and pretty naturalistic looking like this. Don't have to fiddle with keyframes or nothing.

[image]

With that you get a result like this: (hopefully it comes through the video compression, please excuse the pretty shitty 30 second "stars" i made to test it)

[image]

Comment: I like this, it's a good use of the 4d textures now provided.

Comment: I cant find the power node. I searched for it and nothing. The video did not play. It's just an image.

Comment: Power and Multiply are both a Math Node. It is definitely a video, but I replaced it with another one with the intensity and bloom increased to enhance the effect. Hopefully you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is to animate the value and then use an *F-Curve Modifier*.

Set one keyframe anywhere on the timeline for your emission strength, and then open a *Graph Editor* viewport.  You can open the N-panel in this view to get to the F-Curve modifiers tab.

[image]

Add a *Noise Modifier* to the keyframe and edit the settings to your liking.

[image]

Note: You can *Grab* <kbd>G</kbd> and move the initial keyframe to affect the "baseline" of the curve, and you can add a second keyframe somewhere else to interpolate between the two values while still being affected by the modifier(s).

[image]